# How to create and access persistent volume in KubeFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, persistent-volumes, kubeflow

We have created a KubeFlow cluster on GCP and deployed a ML model through it. Now we want to create a persistent volume and map that volume to a folder in out host machine.
As a first step I have to create a pv so, I have tried this line of code in Jupyter notebook of my GCP instance.

```
vop = dsl.VolumeOp(
            name="create-pvc",
            resource_name="my-pvc",
            modes=dsl.VOLUME_MODE_RWO,
            size="1Gi"
        )
```

which is running successfully. But I am not sure if the volume is been created or not. Also, how to check if the volume is existing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.add_pvolumes({'/mnt': vop.volume})` to your ContainerOp

```
def sample(x): print(x)

op_2 = create_component_from_func(func=sample, base_image='python:3.10.4',)
    op_2_component = op_2(x='hello') \
        .set_image_pull_policy("IfNotPresent")  \
        .add_pvolumes({'/mnt': vop})
```